# Interfaces with structs, by reference using Generics

Tags: c#, generics, struct, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Sorry guys! i am so into the code! that i forgot to put the compiler errors.

Here is a new version of the code simplified!

And this are the errors:

Error   1 The best overloaded method match for 'IWeird.DataBase.ModifyData(ref IWeird.IDataTable)' has some invalid arguments
Error   2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'ref IWeird.Periods' to 'ref IWeird.IDataTable'

The problem:
I can't pass by reference an interface with a struct in it,
what am I doing wrong?

Here is the new example code:

```
class PeriodsProcessor
    {
        public PeriodsProcessor()
        {
            Periods Data = new Periods();
            DataBase DB = new DataBase();

            Console.WriteLine(Data.Value);
            DB.ModifyData(ref Data);
            Console.WriteLine(Data.Value);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    public interface IDataTable
    {
        string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public struct Periods : IDataTable
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataBase
    {
        public void ModifyData(ref IDataTable data) 
        {
            data.Value = "CHANGE";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PeriodsProcessor PeriodsProcessor = new PeriodsProcessor();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Compiler error (if so what)?  Exception (if so what)?  Not working as expected (if so what is it doing)?

Comment: This code compiles just fine in 2010RC.  What error are you getting and on what line?

Comment: Structs are called "value types" because they are passed by value, not by reference. If you want something passed by reference, pass a reference type.  Mutable structs are a very, very bad programming practice anyway; you should ideally never have a setter on a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `DB.ModifyData<Period>(Data);` method call. Your `Data` field is a struct, structs are passed to any methods **by value** which means that each time you call a method **copy** of the struct is created and is passed to the method. So actually your `ModifyData` method is modifying a copy of the `Periods` structure that is thrown away just after the method call.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are not passing an interface with a struct in it, you are passing a struct that implements an interface.  Those are two COMPLETELY different things.  As for solving your problem, I don't see a reason to be using a struct at all, so I'd change Periods to be a class.

Answer (score 1):

[Structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471(VS.71).aspx) are value types, not reference types. If you want to pass it by reference, you're going to have to use the `ref` keyword. Keep in mind though that it's still a value type, and assigning it to another variable is going to create a new struct.